# How to set a binary int?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to coding in C using a Arduino Uno. I would like to do the following:

```
int randomNumber;
int randomNumberBinairy = 0;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
}

void loop() {
  randomNumber = random(1, 16);
  randomNumberBinairy = ((randomNumber, BIN));
  Serial.println(randomNumberBinairy);
  delay(5000);
}
```

This prints out:

```
2
2
2
2
etc..
```

However I would like it to print out the random number (between 1 and 16) in binary. So it should look something like:

```
101
1100
110
10
etc..
```

Any help on this please?

Comment: Arduino is not C! And all data is binary in a **binary** digital computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in arduino you can use the function `bitRead(x, n)`

```
int randomNumber;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
}

void loop() {
  randomNumber = random(1, 16);
  Serial.print(bitRead(randomNumber, 0));
  Serial.print(bitRead(randomNumber, 1));
  Serial.print(bitRead(randomNumber, 2));
  Serial.println(bitRead(randomNumber, 3));
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: I think this is unnecessarily convoluted, **Serial.print** already provides an optional argument *format* which allows you to choose the format of the printed number.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it will be always 0 to 15 you can write a switch-case block that handles 16 different probability. That works faster than bitread(x, n) for each bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your own reference, the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) of **Serial.print** says:

> Serial.print(78, BIN) gives "1001110"
>
> Serial.print(78, OCT) gives "116"
>
> Serial.print(78, DEC) gives "78"
>
> Serial.print(78, HEX) gives "4E"

That is, if you want to print something in **binary** then you only need
to write

```
Serial.print(randomNumber, BIN);
or
Serial.println(randomNumber, BIN);
```

It's simple as that.